# Why do parapgraphs overlap in html document converted from pdf in pdfMiner.six?

Tags: python, html, pdfminer

I'm trying to figure out how pdfMiner.six works (current stable release with Python 3.6). The documentation is not to heavy on examples or tutorial, so I'm going by trial and error. Fortunately the repo does contain a handful of sample files which I can use. I recon these samples should work correctly with the current stable release.

I'm trying to extract text that is both mineable and readable. In short, I want to convert these pdfs to html files, with mostly intact formatting. However, the paragraphs in the sample pdf somehow get overlayed, making the texts unreadable. I played around with LAParams, with different values of line_overlap, line_margin and boxes_flow, but neither of them seems to solve the problem.

Here's my code and a screenshot of my results:

[image: Screenshot showing the overlaping paragraphs]

```
with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as fin:
    extract_text_to_fp(fin, output_string,
                       output_dir=output_dir,
                       laparams=LAParams(line_overlap=0.7, line_margin=0.7, boxes_flow=-1), output_type='html', codec='UTF-8')
    with open(converted_file, 'wb') as fout:
        fout.write(output_string.getvalue())
```